# if-else statement ignored on view (html.erb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have a weird situtation with a RubyOnRails if-else statement.

I have an string named `pregunta[1]` which I obtained in this way:

```
<% pregunta = p1[0].split('|') %>
```

`pregunta[1]` can have 3 possible values: `(+)`, `(-)` or `(?)`.

After that `pregunta[1]` is assigned to another string named `modo` in this way:

```
<font color="#047d7c"><%= modo = pregunta[1] %></font>
```

Depending of the value of `modo`, I need to display different things, in order to do that I need 3 different if-else statements:

```
<%= modo %>

<% if modo == "(+)" %>
  Write something to modo afirmativo
<% end %>

<% if modo == "(?)" %>
  Write something to modo interrogativo
<% end %>

<% if modo == "(-)" %>
  Write something to modo negativo
<% end %>
```

I put the first line `<%= modo %>` in order to check that I am reciving the right value. And it is not adding other stuff like `\n` or something.

On the browser, the **.erb.html** view, is showing the first line `modo` value perfectly with the right value, but the three different if-else statements are completely ignored.

I think, it should have something to do with my sintaxis, because I tried a `case` statement with the same result.

It is not an option to write the code on the controller, I need to have it on the view. Because it is part of another code which I need to have in there.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Here is the full content of `request.POST`:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"3gpg8XPR0d/db7V1a69tPHNHapTNyuILleBHV7KD5UeMrNppCVHl6qfe3cZ9ov6y69+uodvrF7NAQRekkX/RHQ==",
  "~1-pregunta"=>"Futuro Simple | (+) | 3ra. del Plural | to need | necesitar", 
  "1-conAuxiliar"=>"they | will | | need", 
  "1-sinAuxiliar"=>"they | -", 
  "1-espanol"=>"ellos | | necesitarán", 
  "respuestaUsuario-1"=>"content1", 
  "~2-pregunta"=>"Pasado Simple | (-) | 3ra. del Singular(n) | to open | abrir", 
  "2-conAuxiliar"=>"it | did | not | open", 
  "2-sinAuxiliar"=>"No existe", 
  "2-espanol"=>"eso | no | abrió / abría / abriera / abriese", 
  "respuestaUsuario-2"=>"content2", 
  "~3-pregunta"=>"Presente Simple | (?) | 1ra. del Plural | to hurt | lastimar", 
  "3-conAuxiliar"=>"¿do | we | | hurt?", 
  "3-sinAuxiliar"=>"No existe", 
  "3-espanol"=>"nosotros | | lastimamos", 
  "respuestaUsuario-3"=>"content3", 
  "commit"=>"Corregir"
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `p1[0]`?

Comment: Thank you for answering... =).. I got p[0] from a POST call, here the full code from the beggining.

<% argumento = request.POST %>
<% argumento = argumento.to_s.gsub('"','') %>
<% argumento = argumento.gsub('=>',' = ') %>
<% argumento = argumento.gsub('{','') %>
<% argumento = argumento.gsub('}','') %>
<% argumento = argumento.split('~') %>

<% p1 = argumento[1] %>
<% p1 = p1.split(',') %>
<% pregunta = p1[0].split('|') %>
<%= pregunta[0] = pregunta[0].to_s.gsub('1-pregunta = ','') %>

Comment: Sorry the horrible display, this is my first post and comment.

Comment: You don't need to do all that `gsub`, you can just use `requuest.POST` as a hash. What is the content of `request.POST`? And why aren't you using `params` instead?

Comment: try modo = pregunta[1].strip . if you require a stripped string in your conditions you might as well explicitly strip it

Comment: it would also help to know what the original contents of request.POST are, and what you're trying to coerce it into

Comment: Thank you for your answers.... I will implement the request.POST as a hash nad implement the strip... I leave now as well the full content of the POST. I will edit the original post in order to put the full content of the request.POST.

Comment: I will change to params, I have not read enought about it, but I think, it is the right option. Thanks Gerry =)=)....

Comment: all of that `gsub`ing can be replaced by accessing the value in the hash. Try this `pregunta = request.POST['~1-pregunta'].split(' | ')`. Adding the white space into the `split` delimiter (`' | '`) will also ensure you don't keep the white space around the elements of the `pregunta` array, which would also have solved your problem

Comment: I defenitely switch to use params, I am reading about it, and yes... it is the right option... Thank you very much Simon, you answer has helped me a lot, I was reading about that since yesterday =)...

Answer (score 0):

There is undoubtedly a space either side of your pregunta[1](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip) content:
`"Futuro Simple | (+) |`

Your modo variable will therefore match " (+) " with spaces either side. [Strip](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip)/trim the string before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

the **.strip** code made the trick... I will read more about it, and for sure I will start using params instead of POST, thank you for the advise =)=).

**<%= modo = pregunta[1].strip %>**

I really, really appreciate your help... Thank you very much Gerry =) Thank you very much Simon, to all of you =) this was my first post...thank you =)=)=)... I was stuck and sad because I could understand why it wasn't working,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for all suggestions, I leave the code working here using params, with that I didn't need the **.strip** method, I hope people find it useful. =)

```
<% pregunta1 = params[:pregunta1].split('|') %>
<% conAuxiliar1 = params[:conAuxiliar1].split('|') %>
<% sinAuxiliar1 = params[:sinAuxiliar1].split('|') %>
<% espanol1 = params[:espanol1].split('|') %>
<% respuestaUsuario1 = params[:respuestaUsuario1] %>

<p class="verde">
  <font color="#808080">1. </font>
  <font color="#8802f6"><%= pregunta1[0] %></font> 
  <font color="#047d7c"><%= pregunta1[1] %></font>
  <font color="#ff1493"><%= pregunta1[2] %></font>
  <font color="#808080"> con </font>
  <font color="#047d7c"><%= pregunta1[3] %></font>
  <font color="#808080"> / </font>
  <font color="#047d7c"><%= pregunta1[4] %></font><br>
</p>

<% if pregunta1[1] == '(+)' %>

    <font color="#808080">Con auxiliar - </font>
    <font color="#ff1493"><%= conAuxiliar1[0] %></font> 
    <font color="#8802f6"><%= conAuxiliar1[1] %></font> 
    <font color="#047d7c"><%= conAuxiliar1[2] %></font><br>

    <font color="#808080">Sin auxiliar - </font>
    <font color="#ff1493"><%= conAuxiliar1[0] %></font> 
    <font color="#047d7c"><%= conAuxiliar1[2] %></font><br>

    <font color="#808080">En español - </font>
    <font color="#ff1493"><%= espanol1[0] %></font> 
    <font color="#047d7c"><%= espanol1[1] %></font><br> 

    <h4 class="rosa">
        <font color="#808080">Tu respuesta: </font>
        <%= respuestaUsuario1 %>
    </h4>
    <p class="verde">_____________________________________________________________________</p><br>

<% end %>
```